# Maven release plugin adding trunk folder under release tag for release:prepare goal

Tags: maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

My SCM connection information:

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:https://repo/project/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://repo/project/trunk</developerConnection>
</scm>
```

My release plugin configuration:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <tag>RC</tag>
        <autoVersionSubmodules>true</autoVersionSubmodules>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Now when I run `mvn release:prepare`, instead of committing my tagged release under `tags/RC`, it does `tags/RC/trunk`. How do I stop it from adding `trunk` under `RC`?

Comment: Thy did you configure the tag ? If you are using default layout in SVN you don't need to configure that.

Comment: If you don't configure the tag, then it is up to the developer to specify the tag when preparing the release. We don't want that. We simply want the current release tagged, which means it is production ready.

Comment: That's simply wrong. The tag is created by default by the artifactId plus the version. The release plugin will ask you but you can accept the default but if you give -B on command line it will do things automatically without any user interaction but using the defaults (increment of version etc.).

Comment: That still leaves room for error on the developer's part. If the POM has the tag name in it, then it does not ask you what you want to tag it. Besides the fact that still doesn't answer my question, and is actually the opposite of what I want. I don't want it to default to artifactId plus the version. I want the same tag every time.

Comment: Making the same tag every time does not make sense, cause if you release via Maven this will create a new version and related to that is makes no sense. The pom only has a tag name in it if you have a released artifact usually you have a SNAPSHOT version in it which means the trunk in the scm area will be used.

Answer (score 5):

Brian, you may be the victim of Maven's incomplete `release:rollback` feature. See my [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464598/maven-release-prepare-perform-after-rollback-incorrectly-succeeds-with-wrong-co) and the answer to it. If your tag already exists, Subversion (not Maven) will think you want to copy trunk *inside* the existing tag. Delete the tag and it will work - once. Try again and you'll get `RC/trunk`. Try yet again and you'll get an error from Subversion.

The solution is to `svn delete` the tag before you try to copy to it - we do this successfully from Maven during `release:perform`, by binding a couple of plugins to the `deploy` phase.

Basically:

- Let `release:prepare` do its thing, create a tag with a unique name.
- Bind `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:exec` to the `deploy` phase to make it run during `release:perform`. Configure it to call `svn delete <path to RC tag>`.
- Bind `maven-scm-plugin:branch` to `deploy` in order to create the tag fresh using Maven's SCM plugin.

This works for us and it has the added benefit that it gives us the unique tags too for reference. Worst case, you can ignore these tags.

Comment: I can confirm that this is the correct answer (e.g. the release tag already existing in SVN).