# Maven Release: Prepare/Perform after Rollback incorrectly succeeds with wrong content

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

We use Maven with Subversion internally. We also use Maven's Release plugin. We noticed the  issue described below when running through the following (correct, I presume) steps.

**1.** We run `release:prepare`:

- Maven updates the trunk version to `1.0.0`.
- Maven runs `svn copy trunk/myproject tags/myproject-1.0.0`, thus creating tag `myproject-1.0.0`.
- Maven updates the trunk version to `1.0.1-SNAPSHOT`.

---

**2.** We run `release:rollback`:

- Maven resets the trunk version to `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.
- Maven does not remove the tag, because Maven doesn't do this kind of stuff.

---

**3.** We commit more changes to trunk, obviously against version `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`.

---

**4.** We run `release:prepare` again:

- Maven updates the trunk version to `1.0.0`.
- Maven runs `svn copy trunk/myproject tags/myproject-1.0.0`, **thinking** it created tag `myproject-1.0.0` out of the latest trunk. But, alas, Subversion (1.6 and 1.7 alike) will instead create `tags/myproject-1.0.0/myproject` on Maven's behalf.

---

**5.** We run `release:perform`:

- Maven checks out the contents of tag `myproject-1.0.0`.
- Maven builds the contents and deploys the result to Nexus.

The problem is obvious: the change in step 3 did not make it into the tag. We are now releasing `1.0.0` without the change in it.

The questions are: How can we fix this? Is Maven's release rollback feature inherently broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Maven Release Plugin version 3.0.0-M1 `release:rollback` includes scm tag removal. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-229

Answer (score 6):

In fairness, `rollback` should reset the project and SCM to a state that allows a second `prepare` to occur. *This includes removing the tag.* The answer is now apparent (Googling "maven release rollback remove tag"):

http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/rollback-release.html:

> The created branch/tag in SCM for the release is removed. Note: This
>   is not yet implemented so **you will need to manually remove the
>   branch/tag from your SCM**. For more info see [MRELEASE-229](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-229).

The resolution would then be to force `release:rollback` to include a command to delete the SCM tag using something like `org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin`. Short of this, wrap `rollback` inside a script that does that externally.

Comment: The `rollback` now includes scm tag removal since Maven Release Plugin version 3.0.0-M1. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRELEASE-229

Comment: Nice! If you can promote this to an answer, I will mark it accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, release:rollback doesn't have a whole lot of utility when it doesn't clean up SCM.  What our shop has done is setup our Jenkins automation to run "mvn release:prepare release:perform" in combination with the [Jenkins M2 Release Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/M2+Release+Plugin).

If it fails we need to delete the tag in Subversion but, then again, we would have to do this anyway with rollback.

Comment: Slightly off-topic by now, but perhaps you can configure Jenkins to delete the tag automatically if the build fails.